# Flutter : how to get newly added record from firebase real time database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, chat

I'm using below code to retrieve all the data from my firebase chat room

```
void readDataFromFireBase() {

    var databaseReference =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("messages");

    databaseReference
        .child(chatroom.chatId)
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;

      values.forEach((key, value) {
        setState(() {
          chatMessageList.add(ChatMessage(
              value["message"], value["fromUser"], value["timestamp"]));
          chatMessageList.sort((a, b) {
            var formatter = new DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, kk:mm');
            var dateOne = formatter.parse(a.timestamp);
            var selectedDate = formatter.parse(b.timestamp);
            return dateOne.compareTo(selectedDate);
          });


      });
    });
  }
```

now how can i get notify my chat room when the new message has arrived

currently i'm using below code to listen child added event

```
listenDataFromFireBase() {
    var db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("messages");
    db.child(chatroom.chatId).onChildAdded.listen((data) {
      print("GET_NEW_DATA");
      print(data.snapshot.value["message"] ?? '');
      print(data.snapshot.value["fromUser"] ?? false);
      print(data.snapshot.value["timestamp"] ?? '');
    });
  }
```

but there is one issue i'm facing this `listenDataFromFireBase()` load all the the data from particular room

My requirement is whenever new message added in chatroom i want to animate my message layout

How can i get notify my screen whenever new message will add in my chat room.

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: Which specific part is causing problems? 1) notifying the Flutter view? 2) detecting when a new message has arrived after the initial messages have loaded?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the second problem *detecting when a new message has arrived after the initial messages have loaded?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've discovered `onChildAdded` fires immediately for any existing data, and after that also when any data is added. If you want to distinguish between these two cases, you'll need to combine an `onChild` listener and an `onValue` listener.

In the `onValue` listener, all you do is flag whether that event has happened:

```
databaseReference.onValue.listen((event) {
  setState(() { 
    isInitialDataLoaded = true
  });
});
```

Now do all your data processing in the `onChildAdded` listener, getting the message from the snapshot and adding it to the list. Then use the `isInitialDataLoaded` to detect whether this is initial data, or an update:

```
var db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("messages");
db.child(chatroom.chatId).onChildAdded.listen((data) {
  // TODO: get message from snapshot and add to list

  if (isInitialDataLoaded) {
    // TODO: alert the view about the new data
  }
});
```

So you'll have two listeners on the same node. The Firebase SDK actually detects this situation and only reads the data from the server once, so there is no extra data being transferred in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`onValue`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/lib/src/query.dart#L99):

```
  /// Fires when the data at this location is updated. `previousChildKey` is null.
  Stream<Event> get onValue => _observe(_EventType.value);
```

But if you use `onValue` or `onChildAdded`, it will retrieve all the data under this `chatroom.chatId`, then when you data is added the `onValue` event will be fired again and will give you the new data.

Comment: Hi, is it possible with firestore colelctions too? or just real time database? Can I get new messages sent by any user at that time itself?

Comment: If you mean to keep listening for any new data, then yes there is the method `snapshots()` which returns a `Stream`. @ShotoTodoroki

Comment: So it will work like a real time chat session? Like if both the users sent messages at same time, they will be able to see each others' messages?

Comment: @ShotoTodoroki yes https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen